# Why is the modulo operation returning two different values?

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to calculate the modulo of a large number. But when I try it with two different methods, I get two different answers.

```
long a = 1;
for(int i=1; i<=11; i++){
   a = a*31;
}
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(a%23);
System.out.println(Math.pow(31,11));
System.out.println(Math.pow(31,11)%23);
```

This is the output

25408476896404831

1

2.540847689640483E16

2.0

The calculation with the long is the correct one, so why is Math.pow giving me a different answer?

Comment: Double does not have enough precision to represent the number precisely. logPow should mostly be calculated by repeatedly applying the mod in between the different multiplications to keep the numbers small.

Comment: Because `long` has more bits than `double`. NB `%` isn't a modulo operator. It is a remainder operator. [JLS #15.17.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3).

Comment: @user207421 technically long has the same number of bits as double, they're just used for different things.

Comment: @matt OK, more bits *of precision.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Math.pow` does double math.

Computers aren't magical.

Grab a piece of paper. Write down the result of computing 1 divided by 3 on this paper, in decimal format.

So, you write 0.333333... and eventually you run out of paper. You now have a paper filled with a LOT of 3s and it still isn't quite perfectly accurate.

A computer has the same issue, except because it counts in binary, almost all values have this problem (even, say, 1 divided by 5, which fits perfectly well on your paper as 0.2, but a computer can't do it precisely).

Nevertheless, the `double` system says it can represent these things.

So, how? By **rounding**. Silently. After all, you only have 64 bits, which means doubles can only be used to store at most 2^64 unique numbers. That's *a lot* of numbers, but nothing like the literally infinite amount of numbers between 0 and 1, let alone between -infinity and +infinity which double more or less oversimplified claims to be able to represent.

That rounding means, amongst other things:

- Only powers of 2 can be stored properly. It is very easy to observe!

```java
double d = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) d += 0.1;
// 0.1 * 10 is obviously 1, so this prints...
System.out.println(d);
// 0.9999999999. Oh. And this?
System.out.println(d == 1.0);
// false! False? Yes! False! Oh dear!
```

0.1 (one tenth) is not a power of 2, so, it aint perfect, and simply adding 0.1 ten times is enough to see real error here - enough to make that no longer equal to 1.0.

- All numbers are rounded to the nearest 'blessed' number, a blessed number is one double can represent exactly. There are slightly less than 2^64 such blessed numbers. They are not equally distributed: The closer to 1.0 you are the more blessed numbers there are. As you move away from that, there are fewer and fewer (I.e. the distance between blessed numbers increases). 2^52 is an important marker point: That is the point where the distance between 2 blessed numbers is **more** than 1.
- All integral values from -2^52 to +2^52 can be represented perfectly. But go beyond that and this is no longer true.
- `double` does support the `%` operator but it is very 'weird' and it is extremely likely you never want to use it.
- `Math.pow` only works on doubles. Java, however, will silently 'cast' ints and longs to double if needed. The result is, in any case, a `double`.
- All integral numbers between 2^52 and 2^63 are representable in `long` values but not (necessarily, a few are) in doubles.

Specifically, 31^11 is representable in `long` but not exactly representable in `double`. Thus, `Math.pow(31,11)` returns the 'wrong' result - it's right in double math, because in double math, which is a very bizarro number system, the meaning of e.g. `a = b + c` is not: "Add b to c and return the result". It is: "Add b to c. Then, round the result of the computation to the nearest blessed number. Then return that".

`Math.pow(31,11)` is no different: It's 'calculate 31^11, then round it to the nearest blessed number, that is the result of the computation'. This number is not the same as 31^11.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm a beginner programmer so I'm just trying to figure out how the data types work with each other.